# Eigenvalues of $A=\mathbf{u}_1\mathbf{u}_1^T + \mathbf{u}_2\mathbf{u}_2^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $\mathbf{u}_1, \mathbf{u}_2\in \mathbb{R}^{N\times 1}$ be real-valued vectors. Assume that $\mathbf{u}_1$ is orthogonal to $\mathbf{u}_2$ (i.e., $\mathbf{u}_1^T\mathbf{u}_2=0$).
Let us consider the following matrix $$A= \mathbf{u}_1\mathbf{u}_1^T + \mathbf{u}_2\mathbf{u}_2^T.$$

Could you please prove that $A$ has two non-zero eigenvalues: $\lambda_1=\|\mathbf{u}_1\|^2$ and $\lambda_2=\|\mathbf{u}_2\|^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

$$Au_1=\left(u_1u_1^t+u_2u_2^t\right)u_1=\overbrace{u_1u_1^t}^{=\left\|u_1\right\|^2}u_1+u_2\;\overbrace{u_2^tu_1}^{=0}=\left\|u_1\right\|^2\,u_1\implies\left\|u_1\right\|^2$$

is an eigenvalue with eigenvector $\;u_1\;$

Answer (score 2):

What is $A\textbf{u}_1$? What is $A\textbf{u}_2$? If you have a vector $\textbf{v}$ that is orthogonal to both $\textbf{u}_1$ and $\textbf{u}_2$, what is $A\textbf{v}$?

Comment: Thank for consideration. I realize that it turns out that we can prove this by definition, using $Au_{1}=u_{1}(u_{1}^{T}u_{1})$, then we have $u_{1}^{T}u_{1}=||u_{1}||^2$ being an eigenvalue. If we have $v$ that is orthogonal to $u_{1}$ and $u_{2}$, then we have $Av=u_{1}(u_{1}^{T}v) +u_{2}(u_{2}^{T}v)=0$.